# Finding the domain of $f(x)=\ln(3x-4).$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am trying to find the domain of $f(x)=\ln(3x-4)$. I cannot find out how to get the domain. but I did manage to get the vertical asymptote which is $x=4/3$.

Comment: Use that the domain of $\log(z)$ is $z>0$. Now just plug in '$z$' for your case and read off the answer.

Comment: so the answer is x>4/3 so I already had the answer and needed to change the '=' to '>' for domain

Answer (score 1):

So the domain of a function is the set of all $x$ for which $f(x)$ is defined.  The trick here is remembering that the basic natural log function $f(x) = \ln(x)$ is only defined for $x > 0$ (it is the inverse function of $y = e^x$).

Given this, your function can only take inputs when the argument of the natural log is positive.  Therefore, the domain is all $x$ such that $3x - 4 > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The function $\ln(\text{something})$ is defined only and only if that $\text{something}$ is strictly positive, that is $\gt 0.$ (Why?) So here all what you have to do is to recognize that your $\text{something}$ is just the expression $3x-4$. So to know where the function we're discussing is defined, solve the inequality $3x-4\gt0$.